# asp.net mvc web api help page not populating for given route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I am having difficulties having the help page populate for a web api controller. The only method in the controller is the following:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string p1,string p2= "blend", string p3 = "blend")
```

The method appears reflected in the help page with the signature:

```
GET api/mycontroller?p1={p1}&p2={p2}&p3={p3}
```

However none of my comments flow to the help page. For other simple controller `Get(string id)` the help page works ok.

I tried adding the following on the WebApiConfig.cs

`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "mycontroller",
                routeTemplate: "api/mycontroller/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    p1 = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    p2 = RouteParameter.Optional,
                    p3 = RouteParameter.Optional

                }
            );`

But still the help page is not getting populated with the comments written for summary, param description or return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to solve this with convention based routing in the setup I would use [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

First enable it in the WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Then decore the method in the controller with the route

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/mycontroller")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get1(string p1, string p2= "blend", string p3 = "blend")
//Call this api/mycontroller?p1=valueOne&p2=valueTwo&p3=valueThree

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/mycontroller/{p1}/p2/p3")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get2(string p1,string p2= "blend", string p3 = "blend")
//Call this api/mycontroller/valueOne/valueTwo/valueThree
```