# Web API Help Pages discover API but can't show API description page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have installed WebApi HelpPages on an existing project. I can see list of API's (including areas api's). But clicking on link just don't work to see details of API. I can't figure what i misunderstand.

[image: Help Page Web Api link doesn't work]
Api itself work fine at http://localhost:23310/**clases**/api/_fakeTestApi/SumOver/3

maybe something with routing ?

We are using dozens of api's around areas in project without any kind of problem.... Only trying expose some of them.

**Edit1**
Thinking on routing, based on [Marcus Höglund answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46001316/2793845) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001022/asp-net-mvc-web-api-help-page-not-populating-for-given-route) I have already intent `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`  in WebApiconfig and:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/myNewRoute/SumOver")]
    public HttpResponseMessage SumOver(int id){
        //do some stuff     
    }
```

Same result here....

[image]

Comment: You need to call api using `localhost:23310/api/_fakeTestApi/SumOver/1` on your browser.

Comment: @Div no problem with calling API with browser or postman. Only with helppages to show it. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really solved, but [ASP.NET Core web API help pages with Swagger / OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-2.2) work fine... using config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();